# Binary Search Tree insertion error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree, insertion

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

class node<T>{
    T data;
    node<T> left;
    node<T> right;
}
public class binarytree {

    public static void main(String [] args){
    node<Integer> root = null;
    node<Integer> n = new node<>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    root=create(s.nextInt());
    System.out.println("root creates");
    //root=insert(n,root);
    for(int i =1;i<6;i++){
        n=create(s.nextInt());
        insert(n,root);
        System.out.println(i+"th inserted ");
        inorder(root);
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
    private static void inorder(node<Integer> root) {
        if(root==null){
            return;
        }
        inorder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.data+" ");
        inorder(root.right);
        return;
    }
    private static void insert(node<Integer> n, node<Integer> root) {
        if(root.left==null&&root.right==null){//line 37
            if(root.data>n.data){
                root.left=n;
            }
            else{
                root.right=n;
            }

        }
        else if(root.data>n.data){
            insert(n, root.left);//line 47
        }
        else{
            insert(n, root.right);
        }

        return ;
    }
    private static node<Integer> create(int data) {
        node<Integer> n = new node<>();
        n.data=data;
        n.left=n.right=null;
        return n;
    }
}
```

The code works fine with positive small integers, but gives null pointer exception with certain inputs like:

```
2 -3 1 -44
```

and it stops and gives nullpointer exception.

however with some like this, it works fine

```
6 4 3 2 1
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at array.binarytree.insert(binarytree.java:37)
    at array.binarytree.insert(binarytree.java:47)
    at array.binarytree.insert(binarytree.java:47)
    at array.binarytree.main(binarytree.java:21)
```

Comment: Can you put your stack trace and indicate which line it fails at?

Comment: Have you considered what happens when `root` is null?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement in the insert is short-circuiting when `root.left == null` is false and allowing `root.right` to fall through, and then you pass down `root.right` in the recursion, which is null. OR your tree is empty and the root is just null.

Try to restructure like so

```
private static void insert(node<Integer> n, node<Integer> root) {
    if (n == null) return;
    if (root == null) {
       // TODO: Set the root? 
    }  

    Integer data = n.data;
    Integer rootData = root.data;

    if (data < rootData) {
        if(root.left == null){
            root.left = n;
        }
        else{
            insert(n, root.left);
        }
    }
    else if(data >= rootData){
        if (root.right == null) {
            root.right = n;
        } else {
            insert(n, root.right);
        }   
    }
}
```